# Is there a way to get the correct bounding rectangle from SVG data, using any Qt library class?

Tags: c++, qt

If the SVG data has some pixels situated outside the view box, how do I get the bounding rectangle which takes into account these pixels too.

A typical example is something like this :

```
<svg id="L.T.S.P" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 160 160" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><title>layer</title>
<desc>My Picture</desc>
<ellipse cx="80" cy="80" rx="60" ry="60" fill="none" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="2"/>
<text x="80" y="102" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial" font-size="48pt" fill="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="0.25" style="direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">T</text>
<g id="port" transform="matrix (1.22e-017, -0.2, 0.2, 1.22e-017, -20, 100)"><polygon points="60,**180** 140,180 160,200 160,40 140,20 60,20 40,40 40,200" fill="none" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="10"/>
<polyline points="60,60 140,60" fill="none" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=""/>
<polyline points="60,100 140,100" fill="none" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=""/>
<polyline points="60,140 140,140" fill="none" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=""/>
<polyline points="100,20 100,0" fill="none" stroke="rgb(139, 69, 19)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=""/>
</g>
<g id="inputTemperature" transform="matrix (-0.2, -2.45e-017, 2.45e-017, -0.2, 180, 100)"><polyline points="0,100 200,100 80,40" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 0, 0)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=""/>
<polyline points="80,160 200,100" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 0, 0)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=""/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [QSvgRenderer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsvg/qsvgrenderer.html#boundsOnElement) to get the bounding box on the top most element id (in this case "L.T.S.P").

Answer (score 0):

I think Wes's answer is correct.  But I think the question might mislead others about what the svg viewbox represents: a specification of a transform between coordinate systems, not a bounding box that the drawing is clipped to.  The svg width and height attributes defines the bounding box. For the svg data you gave, I think it is up to the SVG consumer to determine the bounding box, and QSvgRenderer will do that.